# Xarray latitude variable with 2 dimensions

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

How do I create a xarray variable "latitude" which is arranged as displayed in the image below? The variable has two dimensions : east_west(x),north_south(y). The values only change along y dimension but remain same along x dimension. The numpy latitude array needs to span from 5 to 40 at 0.1 step.
[image]

Comment: And what code do you already have?  This is not hard.

Comment: I can create a meshgrid with east_west and north_south but I am not sure how to "fill" the latitude values in the grid.

Comment: Each row is a constant. Is it `-59.9 + Yaxis / 4`?  It would probably be easier to create an nparray with these values, then convert it to an xarray and add the header rows.  I'm not so familiar with xarray.

Comment: Yes, In this case , it is -59.9+0.25 , the number of Yaxis or Xaxis depends on the range of internal values. Can you help with the np array code for these values? I can take it from there to make it work in xarray. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a one-liner?

```
>>> nd = (-59.9+np.arange(40)/4).reshape(40,1).repeat(40,1)
>>> nd
array([[-59.9 , -59.9 , -59.9 , ..., -59.9 , -59.9 , -59.9 ],
       [-59.65, -59.65, -59.65, ..., -59.65, -59.65, -59.65],
       [-59.4 , -59.4 , -59.4 , ..., -59.4 , -59.4 , -59.4 ],
       ...,
       [-50.65, -50.65, -50.65, ..., -50.65, -50.65, -50.65],
       [-50.4 , -50.4 , -50.4 , ..., -50.4 , -50.4 , -50.4 ],
       [-50.15, -50.15, -50.15, ..., -50.15, -50.15, -50.15]])
```